# Text box value is not updated in ViewModel when changing in the view in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wix, bootstrapper, burn

When I change the text box value, it is not updated in the view model.

This is my text box xaml in the view

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,65,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=InstallPath, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Full xaml for the view,

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <Button Content="Configure Logger" Height="44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,125,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Button Content="Load DB" Height="43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,200,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108" Click="button3_Click" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,36,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="SQL Server" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,36,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" />
    <GroupBox Header="DB Names" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,114,0,0" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >

    </GroupBox>


    <TextBlock Text="Test bootstrapper application." Margin="10" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,65,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Installation Path" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,65,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=InstallPath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    <Ellipse Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="6" Margin="278,129,216,112"
             Visibility="{Binding Path=IsThinking, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Ellipse.Stroke>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.9"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Stroke>
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="Rotator" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" Angle="0"/>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <Ellipse.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Ellipse.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="Rotator" TargetProperty="Angle">
                        <DoubleAnimation By="360" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Ellipse.Triggers>
    </Ellipse>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="Install" Command="{Binding Path=InstallCommand}" Visibility="{Binding Path=InstallEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Margin="10" Height="20" Width="80"/>
        <Button Content="Uninstall" Command="{Binding Path=UninstallCommand}" Visibility="{Binding Path=UninstallEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Margin="10" Height="20" Width="80"/>
        <Button Content="Exit" Command="{Binding Path=ExitCommand}" Margin="10" Height="20" Width="80" />
    </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
```

ViewModel

```
 private string installPath;
    public string InstallPath
    {
        get { return installPath; }
        set
        {
            installPath = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("InstallPath");                
        }
```

Method which consumes the text box value in WIX Bootstrapper

```
 protected override void Run()
 {            

    MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel(this); 
    BootstrapperDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;         

    MainView view = new MainView();            
    view.DataContext = viewModel;
    this.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "My text input is: " + view.textBox2.Text);
    viewModel.Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["MyBurnVariable1"] = viewModel.InstallPath;

}
```

viewModel.InstallPath is empty even though I change the value in textbox, Do I miss something?

I am just following the below WIX Bootstrapper example explained in the below link,
http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/

Comment: please add the complete xaml of your view. maybe the DataContext of the TextBox is not correct. Is the `TextBox` part of the `MainView`? Is the property `InstallPath` part of the `MainViewModel`?

Comment: use Snoop to check your binding at runtime. http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: i have checked your problem it is working fine in my case..just put break point on set and get of install path and check when you edit your textbox ..then you are going on those point or not..and just update below afterthat..

Comment: @tanuj, Thanks! Probelm is with WIX Bootstrapper, Run method is executed when applicaiton is invoked, after that event it is not updating, I need to force thorugh event, I am debugging further.

Answer (score 11):

Your bindings and setups seems ok with the code you have provided.

You should note that the default `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the `TextBox` is **LostFocus**, so that your property is only updated when the TextBox lost focus.

You can change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to **PropertyChanged**, so that every time Text is written in the TextBox your property gets updated.

You set up the UpdateSourceTrigger in the binding as follows

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=InstallPath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Jehof! I tried the same but still it fails to update.

Comment: @Rahul do you get binding errors while debugging the application in Visual Studio

Comment: No, I didn't get any binding error. it is just empty. But event raise property changed is fired in the viewmodel and value is not updated.

Comment: You are a star, being struggling with this for hours, combobox updates the entity but the text box did not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChange** in order to reflect your view change Back into ViewModel.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=InstallPath,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChange}"/>
```

Comment: Por 3 minutos atrasados bro